# Why is 500/1000 is printing 0?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand why `print(500/1000)` print `0` ?

It should be `0.5` but it's not printing it?!

This happed to me when I started to show a progress bar based on total value and current value but I came across this issue and now I'm stuck

Comment: print(500.0/1000.0)

Answer (score 1):

You are working with whole numbers, so it's returning a whole number.

If you use decimals, it should divide as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really in Swift, but I assume that in this language 500 and 1000 are both integer values (like in other programming languages).

Then `500/1000` is `0`, with a remainder of `500`.

If you want to have a fractional result, you should consider to use the proper datatype (I don't know what this is in Swift ... something like double or float, I assume): write `500.0/1000.0`.